# Differene between 2 where conditions which looks similar

Tags: sql, h2, sql-like

My mind is blind when I see those 2 where conditions and I can't understand what's the difference.
Can someone explain me? First returns 273 records and the second one returns 93. I thought they should return the same records.

1st

```
    s.value LIKE '%One Travel%'
    OR s.value LIKE '%One RSA%'
    OR s.value LIKE '%One Other%'
    OR s.value LIKE '%GP&U%'
    OR s.value = ' '
```

2nd

```
    s.value LIKE (
    '%One Travel%'
    ,'%One RSA%'
    ,'%One Other%'
    ,'%GP&U%'
    , ' ')
```

Comment: Simple.  The first is valid SQL.  The second is not.  What database are you using?  The second should be returning a syntax error.

Comment: Both are valid and returns records in H2 database

Comment: Please share more details - start by tagging your question with a database system

Comment: I've attached everything. I've got 2 queries with above where condition. One of them returns 273 records second one 97. I can't understand why. I am wondering if H2 treats first one as invalid and just skips that or perform some merge of those conditions

Comment: The second query will fail on essentially every other database. Don't get used to it.

Comment: You should probably check up on how the LIKE (comma,separated,parameters) operator works on H2. It may not do a multiple OR which is what the SQL does but a more narrow concatenated OR? That aside, your SQL has = " "  whereas the second text includes the " " inside the Like()

Comment: The real question is which one give u the right response.... the first give u 273 records and second 97. Then one give u too much ou second forget some records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LIKE` in the second command is not a function, it is actually the same `LIKE` predicate. But its right-hand argument is specified as a row value.

I guess many DBMS throw an error, but H2 tries to convert all values here to a character string instead, in some rare cases it is useful, but in this case it isn't.

```
something LIKE (
    '%One Travel%'
    ,'%One RSA%'
    ,'%One Other%'
    ,'%GP&U%'
    , ' ')`
```

becomes

```
something LIKE 'ROW (%One Travel%, %One RSA%, %One Other%, %GP&U%,  )'
```

in recent versions of H2 or

```
something LIKE '(%One Travel%, %One RSA%, %One Other%, %GP&U%,  )'
```

in older versions (they don't support row values, but they treat such expressions as non-standard arrays).

Both expressions are meaningless. You need to use the first command with multiple `OR` conditions. Alternatively you can use a complex regular expression with non-standard `REGEXP` operator (with similar to `LIKE` syntax) or with also non-standard `REGEXP_LIKE` function.

Actually `VALUE` is a keyword, so both these commands cannot be executed by H2 (at least by its recent versions), but I assume it was just a replacement of a real column name.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know H2 at all, but I assume the second query evaluates to:

```
s.value LIKE '%One Travel%'
    OR s.value LIKE '%One RSA%'
    OR s.value LIKE '%One Other%'
    OR s.value LIKE '%GP&U%'
    OR s.value LIKE ' '
```

So you're left with the difference between `s.value = ' '` and `s.value LIKE ' '`. Apparently H2 follows ANSI SQL, and the ANSI standard ignores trailing spaces in comparisons (actually the strings to be compared are padded with spaces till they are the same length). So `s.value = ' '` returns TRUE for `' '`, but also for `''` and `'       '`. `LIKE` doesn't pad spaces to compare, since it is used for pattern matching rather than equality tests. Hence, `LIKE ' '` only matches a single space.

In short; your first query returns more rows because rows where `value` is an empty string or multiple spaces, are also returned. Your second query returns only rows where `value` is a single space (ignoring the other conditions for simplicity).